# draggable element changes its margins when position is relative

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 axis: "x",
 tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:center;
}

.child{
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 9px;
border-radius:9px;
background:gold;
margin:0 9px;
cursor:pointer;
vertical-align: top;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>323</div>
<div class='child'>525</div>
<div class='child'>727</div>
</div>
```

when I drag `child` for the first time - it's ok.
when I drag it again - it changes margins.
removing `position:relative` from `child` - solves the problem, but I need it to be `position:relative` because I have another `absolute` alement inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, it seems like this is a glitch within the jQuery UI library.  I wrote a simple work around for you.

Change this code from this:

```
$('.parent').sortable({
  containment: "parent",
  axis: "x",
  tolerance: 'intersect'
});
```

to this:

```
$('.parent').sortable({
  stop: function() {
    $('.child').each(function() {
      $(this).css('top', '');
    });
  },
  containment: "parent",
  axis: "x",
  tolerance: 'intersect'
});
```

For some reason, jQuery UI is adding a css `top` attribute to the child class after it's moved.  The `Stop` function, which runs after you drop the currently dragged item, manually removes that `top` attribute.

**Here's the working fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/p2709umw/